# Rails4 validation uniqueness scope check for more than two condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have following validation for my email in the model

```
:uniqueness => { :scope => :company_id, :message => "Email has already been taken" }
```

How to give two scope condition for validating uniqueness

:uniqueness => { :scope => `:company_id and :status => 0`, :message => "Email has already been taken" }

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
:uniqueness => { :scope => [:company_id, :status], :message => "Email has already been taken"}, if: Proc.new { |obj| obj.status == 0 }
```

Comment: I knew this but how to set :status value like { :status => 0 }